# Method is not available, requires "unneccessary" rewrite?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, syntax, operator-precedence

I have these two Selenium/Java calls:

```
List<WebElement> aList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//something"));
List<WebElement> bList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//something"));
```

In the first example, the XPath points to the element content (e.g., `<b>element content</b>`) and fills the aList with a bunch of strings.

For `bList` I would like to use `getAttribute("alt")` (that returns the string value for an alt-attribute in a HTML-tag) on the nodes that are found and save the resulting strings in bList but that method is not available/applicable if I do something like this:

```
List<WebElement> bList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//somethingElse")).getAttribute("alt"); //doesn't work
```

Why is that? Do I really need to

```
bList.get(1).getAttribute("alt");
```

? That is, access each returned element one by one and call `getAttribute` on them. It would be nicer if I could do all this in one line, like I do for aList.

To clarify:

1. This is mostly a Java syntax question.
2. An example of how it might look. I have several html elements that matches the `something`-XPath that looks like this `<b alt="EN">some text</b>.` I want `some text` to go into `aList` (this works) while `EN` should go into `bList`. How do I write that, the `bList`-case, as a oneliner?

Answer (score 2):

Yes selenium method: `.getAttribute()` only works for one WebElement and not a whole list so you should apply the for loop as you said ...

like that :

```
List<String> blist = new ArrayList<>();
    for (WebElement el:alist) {
        blist.add(el.getAttribute("alt"));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `aList` and `bList` variables are both `List`s which contain a collection of items and not just a single item. In order to use `.getAttribute()` on it, you could use a loop and process each one individually or since you want a one-liner, you can use `stream()`.

A simple example would be

```
List<String> aListStrings = aList.stream().map(e -> e.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This code takes the `aList` collection, iterates through it, and pushes the text (using `.getText()`) into `aListStrings`.

Having said that, I would suggest what I think is a more efficient approach. From your posted code, it looks like `aList` and `bList` are the same collection of elements. If this is the case, you don't need two instances of the same list. Also, since you seem to want to collect the alt attribute along with the text from the same element, I would store them together so you have easy access to both at the same time.

Given all that, I would write the code more like

```
// store all the elements in a single variable List
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//something"));
// initialize a List that will contain the pair of strings, alt text and the contained text
List<Pair<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();
// use a .stream() to map the alt text and contained text values into the Pair instance and return as a list
list = elements.stream().map(e -> new Pair<String, String>(e.getText(), e.getAttribute("alt"))).collect(Collectors.toList());

for (Pair<String, String> pair : list)
{
    // do something with those values
    System.out.println(pair.getKey() + "," + pair.getValue());
}
```

I created a simple HTML file based on your example that looked like

```
<b alt="EN">some EN text</b>
<b alt="DE">some DE text</b>
<b alt="ES">some ES text</b>
```

When I ran the code above, on the mocked HTML it outputs

```
some EN text,EN
some DE text,DE
some ES text,ES
```

I added the code to print the values as an example of how to access the two values. You can remove that and do whatever you want with it inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you questions, just the below one line is enough.

```
List<String> blist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//something")).stream().map(a->a.getAttribute("alt")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Yes. Stream is really making our life easy. In most of the cases, you can skip the for loop.